# Can we reference Kendo.mvc dll licensed version through nuget which we got from Telerik team

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, kendo-ui, telerik, nuget

I got kendo.mvc dll from telerik team, can we get reference of this dll through Nuget?
Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the [Telerik documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/nuget-install)? They also offer full [Visual Studio](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/vs-integration/introduction) integration (setup guide [here](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/introduction)).